# How does an asp.net MVC model generate input names?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In an EditorFor view in MVC with Razor markup, if you do this:

```
@Html.TextBox("")
```

The HTML comes out with the correct input name for the model, like so:

```
<input id="usr_Roles" name="usr.Roles" type="text" value="">
```

The "usr.Roles" name comes from this EditorFor line:

```
@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => usr.Roles, "RoleList")
```

Unfortunately, I'm trying to generate a set of checkboxes with the name "usr.Roles".  Because of the way MVC renders checkboxes, I can't use Html.Checkbox.  I can generate them manually like so:

```
@foreach (string roleName in Roles.GetAllRoles())
{
    string checkboxId = "checkbox_" + roleName;
    <input type="checkbox" name="usr.Roles" id="@checkboxId" value="@roleName" @Html.Raw(Model.Contains(roleName) ? "checked" : "") />
    <label for="@checkboxId">@roleName</label>
}
```

The above works, but only because I manually specify "usr.Roles" as the checkbox name.

My question is this:  Where in the maze of objects and properties does the `@Html.TextBox` object find the "usr.Roles" "usr-Roles" strings?  And can I find it myself and use it in the checkboxes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know why on earth you would be wanting to manually generate ids and names of your checkboxes instead of simply using the `Html.CheckBoxFor` helper which does all this for you, but in case you have some reasons, here's how:

```
@{
    var name = ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("");
}

@foreach (string roleName in Roles.GetAllRoles())
{
    string checkboxId = "checkbox_" + roleName;
    <input type="checkbox" name="@name" id="@checkboxId" value="@roleName" @Html.Raw(Model.Contains(roleName) ? "checked" : "") />
    <label for="@checkboxId">@roleName</label>
}
```

Obviously that's shown here pure for some educational purposes. I would really avoid such monstrosity and simply use Html helpers and editor templates. Another thing that shocks me in your view is the following line of code: `Roles.GetAllRoles()`. It's as if your view is querying data. That's last thing a view should do. It's the controller's responsibility to query data, fill a view model and pass this view model to the view so that it simply shows the data.

So let's try to elaborate your example. From what I can understand you are trying to show a list of checkboxes for each role so that the user can select them.

As always you start with a view model expressing your views requirements:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<RoleViewModel> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class RoleViewModel
{
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

then you write a controller action which will query your data and fill the view model:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var roles = Roles.GetAllRoles();
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        Roles = roles.Select(role => new RoleViewModel
        {
            RoleName = role,
            Selected = ??????
        })
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

then you will have a `Index.cshtml` view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Roles)
```

and a corresponding editor template which will be rendered for each element of the Roles collection (`~/View/Shared/EditorTemplates/RoleViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model RoleViewModel
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Selected)
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Selected, Model.RoleName)
```

No more `foreach` loops in the views, no more ugly hacks with names and ids, no more data pulling from the views.

Comment: To answer your original question, the CheckBoxFor method only works if the checkboxes are being used to generate boolean values.  The code even generates a hidden field to ensure that a value is always returned for the checkbox.  I'm trying to return a List<string>, so that won't work at all.

Comment: @Dave, `List<string>`? From checkboxes? Hmm. In the example I have shown you could simply add the name of the role as a hidden field in the editor template and in your post controller action you will get `IEnumerable<RoleViewModel>` which of course will contain the entire list of role names as well as which one were checked or not.

Comment: And yes, what you've described definitely looks like the "right" way to do what I'm trying to accomplish.  But you even answered my original question, as flawed as it was.  Thanks!

Comment: If you're curious, the reason for the List<string> is that the default RoleManager takes arrays as arguments for adding roles, so I figured I may as well start with an array from the model.  I think I'll redo it your way though.  If I'm going to use MVC I may as well use it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

As I can understand you want to generate the property name from your model, 
I suggest you to use the method:

```
ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText
```

from System.Web.Mvc assembly